# Auto highlght the table row if status change from admin panel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have one application which has admin panel and user panel in laravel.
What i need that when ever user approve any record set from adminpanel that row on user panel should change its color or notify it automatically for some time then this change has occur.

I am not in mood to use ajax calls running continously on the page

Comment: You can use event listeners for that https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/events

Answer (score 0):

> WebSockets are used to implement realtime, live-updating user
>   interfaces. When some data is updated on the server, a message is
>   typically sent over a WebSocket connection to be handled by the
>   client. This provides a more robust, efficient alternative to
>   continually polling your application for changes.
>
> To assist you in building these types of applications, Laravel makes
>   it easy to "broadcast" your events over a WebSocket connection.
>   Broadcasting your Laravel events allows you to share the same event
>   names between your server-side code and your client-side JavaScript
>   application.

Check Laravel [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting)